# NLP should I choose Python 2 or 3 (for a PHP convert)

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I am ordering my holiday reading and among other things want to brush up my Python skills.

Last year I did the "[Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/)" course and enjoyed learning another scripting language immensely.  However, the rule of 'use it or lose it' kicked in as a result of having to earn a living (largely PHP).

I want to pick up where I finished off and I have 2 questions for you:

1. The area I have identified that I want to make Python work for me is NLP (Natural Language Processing), do the best Python libraries for NLP work now with Python 3 or should I just stick to Python 2.x ?
2. Given my skillset (PHP, fairly strong OOP skills now [Refactoring, POEAA, GoF books etc]) what is the best Python book you would recommend me?

Thanks.

Comment: In answer to question 1 - I know the Python library [nltk](http://nltk.org/) is still in alpha for Python 3.x. However, I think the alpha is still usable, and the advantages of Python 3.x (in my opinion) outweigh lack of libraries (although I think most common libraries have been ported).

Comment: A + for Python 3.X - especially regarding NLP - is the "all text is unicode"-dictum . When you're dealing with umlauts and so on, encoding/decoding in Python 2.X can be a pain in the ass.

Comment: As it seems I'm on the way to having this question closed, could some kind soul inform me where I should ask a question such as this then? I really did um and ah before posing it and I did search for similar "recommend me a book ..." style questions.

Comment: NLP has many aspects to it. For comparison, Py2 has stable NLTK, Numpy, Scipy, Scikit; Py3 has a cleaner language (including unicode handling that dorvak mentioned) and a improved default libraries. If your NLP involves largely statistical algorithms, you're better off with Py2 for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One short answer: **Python 2.7**

Because it's popular and experienced. More over a lot of apps are already written in 2.7 and hence you have a rich documentation and lot of sample code...

I'm currently taking a Stanford NLP course and find it really comfortable to use 2.7

Answer (score 1):

- For nlp, i use http://nltk.org/index.html heavily. it doesn't support python3 yet (there is an alpha version for python 3).(result: i'd choose python 2.7)
- if you have done studying 'learn python hard way', i guess you have skills to do projects with python. (recommendation: practice)

and also http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/ this might be useful for you.

Comment: Practice.  Yes you are right there!